# Do CAST and CONVER works in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Do `CAST` and `CONVERT` functions work in MySQL?
According to the documentation they should: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html

But when I run

```
SELECT CAST(25.65 AS varchar);
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, 25.65);
```

at the hackerrank.com with **MySQL** selected I receive an error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
> check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
> right syntax to use near 'varchar)' at line 1

In the same time the same commands work fine with **MS SQL Server**. Please tell me if I do not understand something or there is a bug in the site?

Comment: You've provided the link yourself. Can you not put the examples from that page to use? MySql has no obligation to use the syntax SQL Server uses, even when the names of the functions happen to match.

Comment: Do CAST and CONVERT functions work in MySQL - yes they do but the syntax is not the same as sqlserver..

Comment: `CAST` is ANSI SQL, i.e. expected to be portable. However, you need to specify the varchar length, like `CAST(25.65 AS varchar(10))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have referenced the documentation.  You also need to read it thoroughly.  In particular, the [section **convert(expr, type)**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert) lists the allowed types.  Confusingly, these are not the same types used to define values.

So the following works in MySQL:

```
SELECT CAST(25.65 AS char)
SELECT CONVERT(25.65, char)
```

There is a similar problem for `int`, where the corresponding types for `cast()` are `unsigned` or `signed`.

Note that the arguments for `CONVERT()` are in the opposite order from SQL Server.  I have no idea why this is the case.  I do note that this also occurs for `DATEDIFF()` and perhaps for other functions as well.